# How do I make scss / sass / css-loader not resolve url calls? (Inside WebPack)

Tags: webpack, sass

I have several calls to `url(some-path)` in my SCSS file and css-loader is insisting on resolving those URLs to something it knows.  These included files are available on the server/web, but aren't visible to WebPack. How can I get it to just accept the strings?

In my scss file I have a font-face, for example:

```
@font-face {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif';
    src: url($font-path + 'NotoSerif-Regular.ttf');
}
```

And I get an error:

`Error: Can't resolve '/static/fonts/NotoSerif-Regular.ttf'`

I just want it to emit this string without trying to resolve it. I have no rules in my WebPack file that would tell it to include TTF files. I recently upgraded the sass/css/loader node modules; before it was working.

I don't know if the error is coming from WebPack or Sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in the [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) to disable URL resolution:

```
                // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    url: false,
                },
```

One of the version upgrades must have changed the default for this to `true`, making it backwards incompatible.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a way to somehow specify this on a per url basis.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I added the following in my `webpack.config.js` in order to exclude some URLs from webpack resolution:

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    url: {
      filter: (url, resourcePath) => {
        if (url.indexOf("/fonts/")==0) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
    }
  }
}
```